# Is PhP Unit Included Automatically by ZEND?

Tags: php, phpunit

I once asked a question of what's wrong with this code:

```
static $result = null;

if  (isNull($result))
{
    return $result;
}
```

After tons of downvotes (the questions are gone), the problem is that there is no such thing called isNull function. What we have is is_null

Great. I wonder how I ended up using isNull in the first place.

Turns out it's the autocomplete working.

Now I found out why I type isNull. The function actually exist. I press ctrl click and I go to

```
/**
 * Returns a PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_IsNull matcher object.
 *
 * @return PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_IsNull
 * @since  Method available since Release 3.3.0
 */
function isNull()
{
    return PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::isNull();
}

/**
 * Returns a PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_IsTrue matcher object.
 *
 * @return PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_IsTrue
 * @since  Method available since Release 3.3.0
 */
function isTrue()
{
    return PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::isTrue();
}
```

It's from a file called functions.php. I don't know what kind of problem is that

```
<?php
/**
 * PHPUnit
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2002-2011, Sebastian Bergmann <sebastian@phpunit.de>.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 *
 *   * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *
 *   * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in
 *     the documentation and/or other materials provided with the
 *     distribution.
 *
 *   * Neither the name of Sebastian Bergmann nor the names of his
 *     contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
 *     from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
 * "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS
 * FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 * COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT,
 * INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING,
 * BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES;
 * LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER
 * CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT
 * LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN
 * ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
 * POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 *
 * @package    PHPUnit
 * @subpackage Framework
 * @author     Sebastian Bergmann <sebastian@phpunit.de>
 * @copyright  2002-2011 Sebastian Bergmann <sebastian@phpunit.de>
 * @license    http://www.opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.php  BSD License
 * @link       http://www.phpunit.de/
 * @since      File available since Release 3.5.0
```

What is that? Any idea how that file got into my PHP? I never remember having that file before.

I never added this framework. Not that I know off. Yet it's there. It must be some powerful framework.

How do I know how autocomplete think that it's part of my code? I tried show in explorer, show in navigator, nothing. There is no option to show in windows explorer.

PhPUnit must be a famous framework that it got into my code without me knowing about it. Is it installed by ZEND automatically?

Comment: you're asking how phpunit got onto your computer?

Comment: How it got into your PHP installation I don't know, but it's a framework, which allows you to test your scripts for errors. Google is your friend.

Comment: WHat is so unreal about this question if I may know?

Comment: @Stu, yes that's basically what I am asking.

Comment: We sympathize with your confusion, Jim, but basically what you are asking is like you open your refrigerator door and you see beer in there, and you are standing there in front of the refrigerator with the door open and asking everyone in the room how the beer got in your refrigerator. *Somebody* had to put it there.

Comment: If you include PHPUnit in your IDE, it will then be able to find the internal functions as you type, and then, the auto complete may match your typing of isNu to be isNull.

Comment: I never include PHPUnit on my IDE. I used ZEND. Is it included automatically?

Answer (score 5):

`isNUll()` is a function from PHPUnit that is a "project" (PHP Framework).

Your question seems like:

```
<?php
 if(myFooRandomFunction($a,$b,2,3.14))
 {
  //do something
 }
}
```

what is `myFooRandomFunction()` and what this will do?

It has no sense (since we talk about php's functions)!

## HOWEVER

```
PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::isNull()
```

is a function of that framework for testing your values against this assertion. Obviously, the name `isNull` isn't random and is written as is, for make it recognizable from php's standard

Comment: What framework is there? It's not myFooRandomFunction(). I did not write that function. It seems like a famous framework.

Comment: @JimThio Is PHPUnit as all answers suggested you

Comment: What the hell is PHPUnit  and how does it get into my framework list etc/ Is this zend thingy?

Comment: @JimThio: calm down man.. How does it get? How can I answer to this question? Maybe was here, maybe you put it here... Don't know, project isn't mine dude

Comment: Because PHPUnit must be something famous for that to got into my project. I thought people are familiar with it.

Answer (score 2):

PHP Unit testing is a PEAR library made to **test** PHP code and assert whether certain conditions are met in compartmentalised code.

`isNull()` Is NOT an inbuilt PHP function.

Comment: If it's not inbuilt why it's on autocomplete? What framework is that?

Comment: PHPUnit as mentioned in the comments you posted and also in the answer above. It's on autocomplete as your IDE has the framework in its project build.

Comment: Is this included in ZEND?

Answer (score 1):

PHPUnit is a unit testing framework. When you (or someone) added it to your code, its functions apparently became available everywhere in your code.

This is a common situation in programming, not just in PHP. It happens in every language -- you can add other people's code or frameworks or addins or plugins and not realize the full implications. Here, your framework has added features (isNull) which will break if you decide to remove PHPUnit. So, using addins can be risky.

Comment: I never added this framework. Not that I know off.